# Combine hooks with each other (hook in a hook)

Tags: feathersjs

Is it possible to make use of a hook like `restrictToOwner` in another hook? For example I want users to be able to update their own information in general only, but I also want them to have access to specific properties of other users. So if a specific query parameter exist, let's say a comment about a user, I want the user to pass and otherwise I want to make use of the `restrictToOwner` hook. Of course I could just write my own equivalent `restrictToOwner` hook, but I would like to make use of the already existing one, if possible(?). The code below isn't working, but I want something like:

```
module.exports = function(options) {
  return function(hook) {
    if (typeof hook.data.comment !== 'undefined')
      return hook;
    return auth.restrictToOwner({ ownerField: '_id' });
  };
};
```

Another similar thing I want to do is executing a hook only if the request is an external call. My internal script should have unlimited access. Something like:

```
// user/hooks/index.js
exports.before = {
  patch: [
    globalHooks.ifExternal(auth.restrictToOwner({ ownerField: '_id' }))
  ]
};
// hooks/index.js
exports.ifExternal = function(func) {
  return function(hook) {
    if (typeof hook.params.provider === 'undefined') //? if internal
      return hook;
    return func;
  };
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`auth.restrictToOwner` is a function that returns another function that consumes a hook object.

So you need to call it like this:

```
return auth.restrictToOwner({ ownerField: '_id' })(hook);
```

To your second question:

```
if (!hook.params.provider) {
  // internal only stuff here.
}
```

Comment: Now I get on both hooks an unhandled promise rejection `Error: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`. Debugging didn't help to find out where the error occurs. `feathers-socket-commons:methods Error calling users::patch +18ms { [TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined]` Do you have an idea?